# How to add a .py format module file to an exe file using auto-py-to-exe

Tags: pyqt5

I have two files: sidebar_ui.py and main.py. main.py calls and uses the setup_ui function from sidebar_ui.py. When I changed it to auto-py-to-exe and only main.py as an exe, it doesn't work. I know I need to include the sidebar_ui file. However, I am hesitant because if I include it as an add file, the python format file will be included as is. What should I do?

Comment: If you're correctly using the program (without unorthodox settings) and your code is properly written, `auto-py-to-exe` should be able to automatically embed the required files: that program is based on pyinstaller, which checks your code against all required imports, which should include the pyuic generated scripts. If that doesn't happen, then there probably is some issue either in the configuration or your own script. Besides, why are you "hesitant"? pyinstaller doesn't do esoteric magic, it just creates a compiled binary of the Python interpreter, the required libraries, and your scripts.

Comment: If you're worried that your code may be "visible" or "reverse engineered", then: 1. Python is not what you're looking for, since it's very easy to "rebuild" python files from their compiled bytecode (they may not be identical to the actual sources, but that's irrelevant); 2. almost any binary built on a common development language can be reverse engineered at some level (if not completely); 3. no system is absolutely and completely inaccessible: consider if your program actually requires that "security level", but if you're worried about the UI, then your preoccupation is **really** misplaced.